# Fill selected columns with chosen input (to external .txt file )

Tags: python, file-handling

#### How it should work

You input 2 columns that exist in a table that is in a txt file.
Then you need to enter a sign for example `*` that will replace all numbers that are in columns that you selected.

#### Expected Output

Should look like this at the end in the txt file:

[image: Should look like this at the end in the txt file]

#### Code

```
m = int(input("M: "))
n = int(input("N: "))

x=int(input("Switch row:"))
y=int(input("and row:"))

doc = open("zadatak1.txt", "w")

for i in range(m,n+1):
    broj=str(i)
    doc.write(broj)
    doc.write("\t")

for i in range(m,n+1):
    doc.write("\n")
    for j in range(m,n+1):
        broj=str(i*j)
        doc.write(broj)
        doc.write("\t")

doc.write("\n\n")
sign=str(input("Enter sign to replace selected rows: "))
doc.write("Row {} and row {} switched with {}".format(x,y,sign))

for i in range(m,n+1):
    if i == x +n-m+1:
        doc.write(str(y+n-m+1))
    elif i == y +n-m+1:
        doc.write(str(x+n-m+1))
    else:
        doc.write(str(i))
    doc.write("\t")

       
for i in range(m,n+1):
    doc.write("\n")
    for j in range(m,n+1):
        if j == x +n-m+1:
            doc.write(str(i*(y+n-m+1)))
        elif j == y +n - m+1:
            doc.write(str(i*(x+n-m+1)))
        else:
            doc.write(str(i*j))
        doc.write("\t")
        
doc.close()
```

How to replace selected columns with `*` ?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: how to replace selected rows with *

Comment: You mean columns? the example image you showed us actually writes * on columns

Comment: fck.... yeah sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = int(input("M: "))
n = int(input("N: "))



doc = open("zadatak1.txt", "w")

for i in range(m,n+1):
    broj=str(i)
    doc.write(broj)
    doc.write("\t")

for i in range(m,n+1):
    doc.write("\n")
    for j in range(m,n+1):
        broj=str(i*j)
        doc.write(broj)
        doc.write("\t")

doc.write("\n\n")
doc.close()
l=[]
x=int(input("Zamjeni stupac: "))
y=int(input("i stupac: "))
znak=str(input("Unesi znak: "))

doc=open("zadatak1.txt","r")
list_of_lists=[]
for line in doc:
    stripped_line=line.strip()
    line_list=stripped_line.split()
    list_of_lists.append(line_list)
doc.close()
list_of_lists.pop()
print("LISTA",list_of_lists)

doc=open("zadatak1.txt","a")

doc.write("Zamjenjeni {}. i {}. stupac sa znakom {}\n".format(x,y,znak))
doc.close()
doc=open("zadatak1.txt","a")



for i in list_of_lists:
    for j,k in enumerate(i):
        if j==x-1 or j==y-1:
            k=znak
            doc.write(znak)
        else:
            doc.write(k)
        doc.write("\t")
    doc.write("\n")
doc.close()
```

Comment: solved, some things are in Croatian but I didn't bother translating

Answer (score -1):

To produce the final matrix, just read the file line by line and save it in `l`, a list of lists. Then, for each line of l, write to your document the correct value for each number in the line: '*' if the index of the number is x or y, the number itself otherwise.

```
x = int(input("Switch row:"))
y = int(input("and row:"))
doc = open("zadatak1.txt", "w")

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    # file content as list of lists
    l = [[int(num) for num in line.split(' ')] for line in f]

sign = str(input("Enter sign to replace selected rows: "))

for line in l:
    for i, number in line:
        if i == x or i == y:
            doc.write(sign)
        else:
            doc.write(number)
        doc.write("\t")
    doc.write("\n")
```

Comment: While this does solve the problem, it's difficult to see why. Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of what you changed, why you changed it, and why it solves the problem.